# Impala : Running sum of 1 hour

Tags: hadoop, hive, hql, impala

I want to count records of each ID with in 1 Hour. I tried out some IMPALA queries but without any luck.

I have input data as follows:

[image]

And expected output would be:

[image]

I tried :

```
select
      concat(month,'/',day,'/',year,' ',hour,':',minute) time, id,
     count(1) over(partition by id order by concat(month,'/',day,'/',year,' ',hour,':',minute) range between '1 hour' PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) request
       from rt_request
       where
    concat(year,month,day,hour) >= '2019020318' 
group by id, concat(month,'/',day,'/',year,' ',hour,':',minute)
```

But I got exception.

**RANGE is only supported with both the lower and upper bounds UNBOUNDED or one UNBOUNDED and the other CURRENT ROW.**

Any suggestion/help would be appreciated. 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: the expected result doesn't seem to align with the description. you should clarify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for counts for the same hour across days for a given id. You can simply use `row_number` to do this.

```
select time,id,row_number() over(partition by id,hour order by concat(month,'/',day,'/',year,' ',hour,':',minute)) as total
from tbl
```